# ODP.net Truncating Timestamp Milliseconds

Tags: c#, json, oracle, datetime, odp.net

I am using ODP.net to get some data from Oracle, and in one specific data set I am getting a field of the type Timestamp. No matter what I do on my end, whether I convert it to DateTime or convert it to string, it always truncates the milliseconds.

This is an example of what is coming back from my stored procedure:

10/28/2016 4:05:53.873 PM

And this is what is what it looks like when I map it to my Model, regardless if the property is DateTime or string:

10/28/2016 4:05:53 PM

Here is what my procedure call looks like:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "Schema.Package.someProcedure";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_1", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_output", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output));

cmd.Parameters["P_1"].Value = someVar;

using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        myObjList.Add(
            new myObject
            {
                prop1 = Convert.ToString(dr["ID_1"]),
                prop2 = Convert.ToString(dr["ID_2"]),
                dtProp = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["TIME_STAMP1"]),
                stringProp = Convert.ToString(dr["TIME_STAMP2"])
            });
    }
}
```

The end goal is to serialize this list of objects into JSON, which the DateTime property presents another issue in that it serializes in this format:

```
\/Date(1477685153873)\/
```

So if at all possible I'd like to convert the Oracle timestamp into a string while keeping the milliseconds. I'm pretty new to ODP.net so am I missing something in how I am accessing the data coming back?

Comment: Instead of parsing, have you tried to use explicit casting instead like `(DateTime)dr["TIME_STAMP1"]`?

Comment: I just tried it and it still removes the milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working but it isn't pretty or as maintainable. I had to use `myTimeStampProp = Convert.ToString(dr.GetOracleTimeStamp(29))` instead of referencing the column by name. Like I said, it's less maintainable without having the column name, but it works.